# Redirecting to another domain with query strings

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I am moving to another domain and I would like to redirect dynamic and static ULRs too. I have tried many .htaccess redirect rules but they don't work. For example:

FROM: http://www.bercsekft.hu/motorosbolt/index.php?id=546

TO: https://www.bercsemotor.hu/k/robogo-alkatreszek/aprilia-alkatreszek/aprilia-kormany-alkatresz

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/index.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^id=509$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://www.bercsemotor.hu/k/robogo-alkatreszek/aprilia-alkatreszek/aprilia-kormany-alkatresz [R=301,L]
```

I have also another rules in .htaccess. I am not sure if they have affect to the redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bercsekft.hu$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.bercsekft\.hu\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bercsekft\.hu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bercsekft\.hu$
RewriteRule ^jarmu\/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.bercsekft\.hu\/motorosbolt" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bercsekft\.hu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bercsekft\.hu$
RewriteRule ^edeny\/?$ "http\:\/\/konyhafelszereles\.bercsekft\.hu\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bercsekft\.hu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bercsekft\.hu$
RewriteRule ^edenybolt\/?$ "http\:\/\/konyhafelszereles\.bercsekft\.hu\/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ motorosbolt/sitemap2.php [L]
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php52” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php52___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loos like your issue is the location of that dynamic configuration file you use (".htaccess") in combination with the paths you defined in there. If you really need to use a dynamic configuration file then it usually is easiest to place it in the http servers `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. You need to make sure that such files are considered at all by the http server (hint: the `AllowOverride` directive) and that the file is readable by the http server process.

This is a slightly modified version of your code to adjust the paths, also I replaced the numerical ID, your question contradicts itself in that detail:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=546(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?motorosbolt/index\.php/?$ https://www.bercsemotor.hu/k/robogo-alkatreszek/aprilia-alkatreszek/aprilia-kormany-alkatresz [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the good advices. I guess the problem was the 301 redirect I made a week ago.